# JADE/SCALATE template error - InvalidSyntaxException

Tags: scala, pug, scalatra, scalate

I'm trying out Jade (via Scalate) and am running into an error that I'm not finding an answer to. (Or, at least not seeing.) I mocked up a form using BlueGriffon (it's been years since I've coded HTML...) and placed the resultant HTML into Aarron Powel's HTML-JADE converter. Here is the top portion or that translation which is in my .jade template file:

> br
>   
> form(method='POST', action='/account/create', name='userAccountDetails')
>   
>   | Username:
>   
>   input(required='required', name='username', type='text')
>   
>   
> etc., etc.,

Trying to run the scala app where this is nested generates this error:

> org.fusesource.scalate.InvalidSyntaxException: `)' expected but`,' found at 5.19
>           at org.fusesource.scalate.scaml.ScamlParser.parse(ScamlParser.scala:375)
>           at org.fusesource.scalate.jade.JadeCodeGenerator.generate(JadeCodeGenerator.scala:38)

It seems to not like the comman-sperated attributes, but I'm not sure why. Aslo, within the stacktrace clip it appears to be pulling in a Scaml parser, even though the file has a .jade extension.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For whomever finds themselves here, the issue (at least for me) appears to be due to syntactic differences between the Scala/Scalatra and JavaScript/NodeJS implementation of JADE. As luck would have it, my searches for JADE examples turned up the latter - both in terms of utilities, as well as forum Q&A - which all indicate the necessity for commas.

Solution: remove the commas and things work as they should:

!!!
h2 New Account Setup
br
form(method='PUT' action='/account/create')

...

EDIT: To be more precise, the discrepancy actually lies within Scalate (the Scala Template Engine) that is integrated by Scalatra. (There may be some other JADE-based scala libraries which following the original syntax.)

Comment: yep, I just lost some time with this same problem. :/